# When searching for the origin of "bootlegger" has anyone considered foreign origin? Namely the low German/Saxon/Norwegian "utlegger"

Tags: etymology

As boots are hardly satisfactory to transport alcohol, the explanations based around boots or legs seem doubtful. Immigrants from northern European coastal areas would be familiar with both smuggling and alcohol so applying the word for outrigger (used colloquially for smugglers in their common unwritten language) doesn´t seem far fetched. When spoken only the "b" is missing which might have been added by nonspeakers of low German/Saxon/Norse.

I´m not a native speaker of english, please excuse my mistakes.

Comment: The idea wasn't to use a boot as a vessel for alcohol, but as the [Online Etymology Dictionary](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=bootleg) gives: *from the trick of concealing a flask of liquor down the leg of a high boot. Before that the bootleg was the place to secret [sic] knives and pistols.*

Comment: *"so applying the word for outrigger (used colloquially for smugglers in their common unwritten language)"* If it is unwritten, how do we know if this is true? In other words, "What is your authority for saying this?" -- I ask as OED has no such definition.

Comment: I'm finding that *utlegger* in Norwegian means "annotator" or "exporter." *Utläggare* in Swedish means "annotator" or "publisher."

Comment: 1. That paranthetical, "used colloquially ...", needs to be sourced, or marked so if it is your opinion. 2. intervocalic b lenites in northsea germanic (*love* ~ German *lieben*, Russian *lubju*, etc.), which, I guess, might happen accross morpheme boundaries, perhaps with a tendency to vowelize in initial position, so that *b-* might be original. 0. I concure, nothing to do with boots or legs.

Comment: The origin of "bootleg" is discussed in great detail in one of the answers to the EL&U question [What is the origin of bootleg?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/13406/what-is-the-origin-of-bootleg). Have you read the question and answer there?

Comment: Thank you. In a 1793 German dictionary "utlegger" is described as "Wachtschiff" which translates as "guard ship". Reading up on Hans Pothorst brought me here who in English language Wikipedia is described as privateer, but in German sources described as utlegger. One mans guard is another´s pirate. Not far from whatever bootleggers do. I´ve read the answers to the EL&U wondering whether anyone had researched on influences from the languages around the north sea. I found the reference to the swedish publisher interesting, the modern german "Verleger" is pretty close to the utlegger as well.